# R: Creating a timeseries out of multiple timespans

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart

I have data in the following form:

```
startDate             | endDate              | type
---------------------------
2017-04-11 10:45:06.0 |2017-04-11 10:47:30.0 | Type1
2017-04-11 10:15:01.0 |2017-04-11 11:47:33.0 | Type2
2017-04-11 10:44:09.0 |2017-04-11 10:50:00.0 | Type1
2017-04-11 10:35:06.0 |2017-04-11 10:53:33.0 | Type2
```

My aim is to visualize it in a [time-series](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ts.html). But as far as i understand it i need data in the form of a vector depicting the frequencies per point of time.
Is there a library or a nice way to transform my data into this form? Or do i have to check each entry for each point of time i want to visualise?

Basically the graph should look somewhat like this:
(Please note that the image does not match the example data)

[image]

Comment: I've solved similar problems using `foverlaps()` from the `data.table` package. You need to specify the time intervals you want to aggregate over. `foverlaps()`finds the intersections which can be counted.

Comment: Your sample data seem not to be correct because in lines 3 and 4 the end dates are earlier than the start dates. In addition, the sample data cover only  minutes or hours within one day while the chart depicts 3 years.

Comment: @UweBlock of course you are right. i simply copied some data without respect to its validity. The orginal data is way more complex (and valid). The image is only an arbitrary example. I will have a look at `foverlaps()` and will post my findings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has specified that he has a number of events with given start and end time and that he wants to depict the *coverage*, i.e, the number of events for each point in time.

There is an exact solution possible using *Bioconductor's* `IRanges` package (see section 5.5 *Counting Overlapping Ranges* in the [IRanges vignette](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/IRanges/inst/doc/IRangesOverview.pdf)).

However, the graph in the Q suggests that a solution using *binning* is acceptable for the OP. Binning means that the number of events are counted which overlap with a time raster. This is similar to creating a histogram except that a particular event may span more than one bin.

The `foverlaps()` function from the `data.table` package can be used for the binning process. But first we need to prepare some dummy data for demonstration.

#### Creating dummy data

We create two types of events. `Type1` are fewer but longer events, `Type2` are a larger number of shorter events.

```
set.seed(1L)
n1 <- 10L
n2 <- n1 * 10L
ref_time <- lubridate::ymd_hms("2017-4-26 10:11:12")
DT <- rbindlist(list(
  data.table(t = ref_time + rnorm(n1) * 60 * 60,
       d = rnorm(n1) * 60 * 60,
       type = "Type1"),
  data.table(t = ref_time + rnorm(n2) * 60 * 60,
       d = rnorm(n2) * 60 * 6,
       type = "Type2")
))
# 
DT[, c("start", "end") := .(pmin(t, t + d), pmax(t, t + d))]  
setkey(DT, start, end)
# add row numbers
DT[, rn := .I]

DT
#                       t           d  type               start                 end  rn
#  1: 2017-04-26 08:11:50   -64.64035 Type2 2017-04-26 08:10:45 2017-04-26 08:11:50   1
#  2: 2017-04-26 08:22:54   -91.80973 Type2 2017-04-26 08:21:22 2017-04-26 08:22:54   2
#  3: 2017-04-26 08:39:47  -528.21001 Type2 2017-04-26 08:30:58 2017-04-26 08:39:47   3
#  4: 2017-04-26 08:42:57   -13.54830 Type2 2017-04-26 08:42:43 2017-04-26 08:42:57   4
#  5: 2017-04-26 09:21:03 -2236.46609 Type1 2017-04-26 08:43:47 2017-04-26 09:21:03   5
# ---                                                                                  
#106: 2017-04-26 11:52:07   183.63903 Type2 2017-04-26 11:52:07 2017-04-26 11:55:11 106
#107: 2017-04-26 11:57:14   899.15817 Type2 2017-04-26 11:57:14 2017-04-26 12:12:13 107
#108: 2017-04-26 12:10:01  -387.06923 Type2 2017-04-26 12:03:34 2017-04-26 12:10:01 108
#109: 2017-04-26 12:21:33    74.71380 Type2 2017-04-26 12:21:33 2017-04-26 12:22:48 109
#110: 2017-04-26 12:35:17   153.03614 Type2 2017-04-26 12:35:17 2017-04-26 12:37:50 110
```

This is better to be visualised:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT, aes(x = start, y = rn, xend = end, yend = rn, colour = type)) + 
  geom_segment(size = 1) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

#### Create time raster for binning

We create a time raster with 15 minute intervals

```
bin_start_time <- DT[, lubridate::floor_date(min(start), unit = "hour")]
bin_end_time<- DT[, lubridate::ceiling_date(max(end), unit = "hour")]
# time interval can be adjusted 
bin_step <- as.difftime(15L, units = "mins")
bin_cuts <- seq(bin_start_time, bin_end_time, by = bin_step)
bins <- data.table(start = head(bin_cuts, -1L),
                   end   = tail(bin_cuts, -1L),
                   key = "start,end")
# add row numbers
bins[, bn := .I]

head(bins)
#                 start                 end bn
#1: 2017-04-26 08:00:00 2017-04-26 08:15:00  1
#2: 2017-04-26 08:15:00 2017-04-26 08:30:00  2
#3: 2017-04-26 08:30:00 2017-04-26 08:45:00  3
#4: 2017-04-26 08:45:00 2017-04-26 09:00:00  4
#5: 2017-04-26 09:00:00 2017-04-26 09:15:00  5
#6: 2017-04-26 09:15:00 2017-04-26 09:30:00  6
```

#### Binning

Binning requires to find all overlaps of events given in `DT` with the time raster using `foverlaps()` and counting the number of overlaps. This can be done in one statement:

```
result <- foverlaps(DT, bins)[, .N, by = .(type, start, end)]

result[18:24]
#    type               start                 end  N
#1: Type1 2017-04-26 11:00:00 2017-04-26 11:15:00  5
#2: Type1 2017-04-26 11:15:00 2017-04-26 11:30:00  4
#3: Type1 2017-04-26 11:30:00 2017-04-26 11:45:00  4
#4: Type1 2017-04-26 11:45:00 2017-04-26 12:00:00  2
#5: Type2 2017-04-26 09:45:00 2017-04-26 10:00:00 14
#6: Type2 2017-04-26 10:00:00 2017-04-26 10:15:00 17
#7: Type2 2017-04-26 10:15:00 2017-04-26 10:30:00 11
```

Note that the frequencies are counted separately by type.

#### Visualisation

```
ggplot(result, aes(start + bin_step/2, N, group = type, colour = type)) + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + expand_limits(y = 0) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Here, the data points are centered at the middle of the intervals of the time raster.

Another possibility is `geom_step()`:

```
ggplot(result, aes(start, N, group = type, colour = type)) + 
  geom_step(size = 1) + expand_limits(y = 0) + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this outstanding answer! This is exactly what i needed and i was able to use it for my means with very little adjustements!

Comment: @Abaddon666 Excellent, that was what I was hoping for.